# Setting titles for a UISegmentedControl from an NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I tried to subclass `UISegmentedControl`.
I'm passing an `NSArray` from the view and try to set the titles for the `UISegmentedControl` from that `NSArray`.
I used the `initWithArray` method but it is not setting the value from the array.

Here is my subclass of `UISegmentedControl`.

**WTSegmentedControl.h**

```
@interface WTSegmentedControl : UISegmentedControl {

}
@end
```

**WTSegmentedControl.m**

```
#import "WTSegmentedControl.h"

@implementation WTSegmentedControl

- (id)initWithItems:(NSArray *)items {
    if (self = [super initWithItems:items]) {

    }
    return self;
}
```

Now from the view I'm calling this method.

I have connected the outlet like this:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet WTSegmentedControl  *control;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSArray *names = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"yes", @"no", nil];
    control = [[WTSegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:names];
}
```

`NSArray` is passing correctly but the `titles` are not set.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: where are you creating control object? Have you imported that class in this class?

Comment: @HinataHyuga i have created this control object my view.Please look that the edited quetion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you are creating the control in the Interface Builder or by code!? You cannot do both.
If you want to create it in code, remove the `IBOutlet` part in your property and add the control to the subView after initializing:

```
// adding the control by code
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *names = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"yes", @"no", nil];
    control = [[WTSegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:names];
    control.frame = CGRectMake(x,z,width,height);
    [self.view addSubview: control];
}
```

But if you want to create it in the InterfaceBuilder, you should not re-initalize it. Set your custom class in Interface Builder and then just set the titles like this:

```
// using Interface Builder
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *names = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"yes", @"no", nil];
    [names enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *title, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [control setTitle:title forSegmentAtIndex:idx];
    }];
}
```

Comment: i need to use this segmeted control in so many parts of my code.so i tried to subclass it and tried to use it as a control(or utility).so that i just to call that method right.is there any way to do that?

Comment: ok. when i give like this  NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"YES",@"NO", nil];
    
     self.UISec = [self.UISec initWithItems:array];
it is working.

Comment: But the issue is title is setting only after we click on segment control.ie,title is not setting when the view is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you have correctly connected your IBOutlet control, then the control variable is automatically set at this point. This is done when the view is loaded.
So the line:

```
control = [[WTSegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:names];
```

should be changed to this:

```
[control initWithItems:names];
```

Comment: i tried this but not working.Also when i so like this im getting an issue "Expression result unused".